# How to clear memory after message_string() in perl

Tags: perl, memory, split

I use perl v5.18.2, and lib `Mail::IMAPClient` version 3.35. Method `message_string` uses a lot of memory if email have big size(attachments). It would not be a problem if it freed after use. But the demon who uses this method does not release this memory. For check i use `Memory::Usage` lib and email with ~30MB size.

```
time    vsz    (  diff)    rss   (  diff) shared (  diff)   code (  diff)   data  (  diff)
         0  34212  ( 34212)  21272   ( 21272)   5124 (  5124)   1504 (  1504)  16208  ( 16208) before message_string
        18  136180 ( 101968)  120632 ( 99360)   5148 (    24)   1504 (     0)  118156 ( 101948) after message_string
```

after call `message_string` i do `split`:

`$message = $imap->message_string($msg);
($header, $body) = split /\n\h*\n/, $message, 2;`

```
time    vsz    (  diff)    rss  (  diff) shared (  diff)   code (  diff)   data  (  diff)
     0  108708 ( 108708)  87560 ( 87560)   5148 (  5148)   1504 (  1504)  90684  ( 90684) before split
     4  141240 ( 32532)  120332 ( 32772)   5148 (     0)   1504 (     0)  123216 ( 32532) after split
```

These two lines occupy 80-90% of the resources used by daemon.

[Bug on cpan](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=61292)

I would be very grateful if you help me with `message_string` method.
Whether there is a less expensive method than `split`?

Source of method:

```
sub message_string {
    my $self = shift;
    my $msg  = shift;
    my $expected_size = $self->size($msg);
    return undef unless(defined $expected_size);    # unable to get size
    my $cmd  =      $self->has_capability('IMAP4REV1')              ? 
                "BODY" . ( $self->Peek ? '.PEEK[]' : '[]' )         : 
                "RFC822" .  ( $self->Peek ? '.PEEK' : ''  )     ;

    $self->fetch($msg,$cmd) or return undef;

    my $string = "";

    foreach my $result  (@{$self->{"History"}{$self->Transaction}}) { 
              $string .= $result->[DATA] 
        if defined($result) and $self->_is_literal($result) ;
    }      
    # BUG? should probably return undef if length != expected
    if ( length($string) != $expected_size ) { 
        carp "${self}::message_string: " .
            "expected $expected_size bytes but received " . 
            length($string) 
            if $self->Debug or $^W; 
    }
    if ( length($string) > $expected_size ) 
    { $string = substr($string,0,$expected_size) }
    if ( length($string) < $expected_size ) {
        $self->LastError("${self}::message_string: expected ".
            "$expected_size bytes but received " . 
            length($string)."\n");
        return undef;
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the memory was used by a program (Perl), you cannot make it return it back to the OS. It might return it later or not. That's why many daemons restart themselves occasionaly.

See also the [FAQ](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq3.html#How-can-I-free-an-array-or-hash-so-my-program-shrinks).

Comment: What then could be the solution for me?